# Error 405 while using PUT method on Postman

Tags: java, spring, postman

I am using Postman and having trouble with using PUT method to update information.

I have following controller:

```
@RequestMapping("api/v1/person")
@RestController
public class PersonController {
    private final PersonService personService;

    @Autowired
    public PersonController(PersonService personService) {
        this.personService = personService;
    }
  

    @PutMapping
    public void updatePerson(@PathVariable("id") UUID id, @RequestBody Person personToUpdate){
        personService.updatePerson(id, personToUpdate);
    }
}
```

```
public int updatePerson(UUID id, Person newPerson){
        return personDao.updatePersonById(id, newPerson);
    }
```

Here is procedure that I update the ***Person*** information:

```
    @Override
    public int updatePersonById(UUID id, Person update) {
        return selectPersonById(id)
                .map(person -> {
                    int indexOfPersonToUpdate = DB.indexOf(person);
                    if (indexOfPersonToUpdate >= 0){
                        DB.set(indexOfPersonToUpdate,new Person(id, update.getName()));
                        return 1;
                    }
                    return 0;
                })
                .orElse(0);
    }
```

Here is my calls from the PostMan. I tried POST, GET and DELETE and they all work fine, but when I used PUT to update data then I got this error:

> 2023-07-09T16:51:04.651+02:00 DEBUG 35932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : PUT "/api/v1/person/ef462667-fbc2-4587-8099-73475e68f33c", parameters={}
>
> 2023-07-09T16:51:04.655+02:00  WARN 35932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'PUT' is not supported]
>
> 2023-07-09T16:51:04.655+02:00 DEBUG 35932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 405 METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED
>
> 2023-07-09T16:51:04.659+02:00 DEBUG 35932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for PUT "/error", parameters={}
>
> 2023-07-09T16:51:04.660+02:00 DEBUG 35932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
>
> 2023-07-09T16:51:04.664+02:00 DEBUG 35932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
>
> 2023-07-09T16:51:04.665+02:00 DEBUG 35932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Jul 09 16:51:04 CEST 2023, status=405, error=Method Not Allowed, path=/api/v1/person/ (truncated)...]
>
> 2023-07-09T16:51:04.673+02:00 DEBUG 35932 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 405

[image]

And here is my dependencies:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Does anyone know what my problem is?

I tried to double check the URL as well as search a few sites for a solution but those didn't work for me

Comment: please share the complete stacktrace and the person object

Comment: Your `updatePerson` method has a `@PathVariable("id") UUID id`, but you've never defined a path that includes any `{id}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your controller like this

```
@PutMapping("/{id}")
public void updatePerson(@PathVariable("id") UUID id, @RequestBody Person personToUpdate){
    personService.updatePerson(id, personToUpdate);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer. This one solved my silly problem :)